# self referencing an object in its assignment

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if there was a way to reference an object when assigning it to a variable. Here is an example of where this question would apply:
Let's say I wanted to assign the substring of a regex to a variable, call it i.
To assign, I could write

```
i = /some_regex/.to_s
```

and then

```
i = i[3...i.length]
```

I could also write it all in one line, like

```
i = /some_regex/.to_s[3.../some_regex/.to_s.length]
```

However, both of these examples seem somewhat redundant and the second approach could become unwieldy with big regex's or multiple method calls. Is there a way to reference the object being changed without having to rewrite everything?

Edit: Sorry for previous ambiguity.

Comment: Not clear what you want to assign `i` to. Also not clear what `i` is doing in the last example.

Comment: Is this just an example or are you actually trying to solve a regular expression problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby evaluates the right side of the equals sign before setting the left side equal to it, so if `i` already exists you can do what you're talking about. A simple example:

```
i = 10
i = i + 1 # now i = 11
```

However, you can't use `i` to define itself. You could use the following two lines:

```
i = expression.match(/\d+[\+|-|\*|\/]/)
i = i[0..i.length - 1] # Note: this is the same as i = i[0...i.length]
```